# Office add-in for word, excel and outlook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ms-office

i've created an word 2010 Add-in with the VS 2012 word Add-in template and ribbon designer component.

It is possible to use this plugin in other office products, like Excel or Outlook if I add the other interop dlls? 
How can I differ which office product (word, excel or outlook) actually is used to run differnt code segments in the add-in?

Or must I create for each an own plugin with own ribbon!?

Please give me some hints.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you link statically to the Office Interop assemblies, then you will need to build a different version for each Office version you plan to support. A much better alternative I would recommend you investigate is to use NetOffice, which provides the Office API in a version-independent form:

http://netoffice.codeplex.com/